# print even number using prolog:

Tags: prolog

How can I print just even numbers in Prolog? This is my code to print numbers from 3 to 1: And how using mult without (*) in anthor example:

```
predicates
    count(integer).
clauses
    count(1) :- write(1), nl, !.
    count(X) :- X > 1, write(X), nl, X1 = X-1, count(X1), !.
```

Comment: If you want to print even number, this `X>1,write(X)` is pretty wrong. It will print any number that is greater than X,that including 3

Answer (score 1):

> How can I print just even numbers in Prolog

```
?- between(1, 3, X), X mod 2 =:= 0.
X = 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ did a nice, concise method. The one below just builds on the approach that was started:

```
predicates
    count(integer).

clauses
    count(X) :-
        X /\ 1 =:= 1, !,  % Using bitwise AND (/\) to check for odd
        X1 is X - 1,
        count(X1).
    count(X) :-
        X > 1,
        write(X), nl,
        X1 is X - 2,
        count(X1).

| ?- count_even(7).
6
4
2
```

I used bitwise AND (`/\`) to check the parity of the number just to illustrate a different method. The `mod` operator works just as well.

Note that for arithmetic expression assignment in prolog, you need `is`, not `=`. `is` will calculate the expression on the right and unify the result to the uninstantiated variable on the left. `=` will not evaluate the expression.

Comment: mbratch, what do u mean in  integer(X),and X /\ 1 please help me because I'm Tyro in prolog programing

Comment: and this error found (undeclared predicate or misspelling) and point on integer(X)

Comment: @eleen sorry `integer` must be specific to certain prolog interpreters. I use GNU, which has `integer`. I just removed it. It's a defensive check to make sure an integer is passed. Since you're using Turbo Prolog and declaring the type as "integer", you don't really need it.

Comment: @eleen, the `/\` operator is a bit-wise and. It's just another way to determine even or odd. An odd number will have a `1` as its first bit. So `X /\ 1 =:= 1` is like saying `X mod 2 =:= 1`. I decided to use it to show an alternative approach.